# Squid HTTPS Proxy : How to notify user

Tags: privacy, squid

I have setup a transparent Squid HTTPS proxy for DLP. I would like to respect user privacy and let them know that their activity is being monitored. How can I notify users about the squid proxy?

Answer (score 1):

You could use squid's Content Adaptation... there's an intersting article about this and another solution [here](http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2011/02/28/squid-greasyspoon-enhancing-your-proxy-deployment-with-content-adaptation/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got the idea for notification after reading that blog post :) I was hoping there would be an easier method.

Comment: Yeah its a bit complex and time consuming, I prefer to let users know about this and other policies by providing a "Usage Policy" informing users about all IT policies and when they first join the company they "have to" read it, not only regarding squid but everything, this way they should know they are being monitored, but I usually don't monitor https.